# How are electrons moving in a metal rod?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

Suppose an electromagnetic wave falls on the length of a metal rod. In what direction would the free electrons there start to move? Up-down or left-right. Intensity vector E is perpendicular to the length of the rod so it must induce up-down oscillations. But the energy (Pointing vector) is always perpendicular to E, B so according to it the movement must be left-right.
Of course this is the situation in antenna bar. It must be something very easy but I can not find info online.

Comment: What do you mean by "up-down" here? What is the position of the bar?

Comment: The movement doesn't have to be in the direction of the poynting vector, see momentum conservation of the EM field. The movement macroscopically follows E, meaning if I were to place the rod perpendicular to the electric component, there would be no PD across the ends of the wire. See "Walter Lewin antenaa"

Comment: https://youtu.be/nFtNCPUMoYA 56:41

Comment: @nasu E is perpendicular to the length of the rod. This is up-down direction.

Comment: @jensenpaull What is PD?

Comment: Potential difference

Comment: @jensenpaull What is PD? The video is useless I must take 1 hour to look at familiar things. Let me know why the movement is not in Pointing direction if you know (something connected with the radiation of the moving charges)?

Comment: If the S=ExB drives the electrons right than there would be PD. They will move to the right end of the wire.

Comment: That's why I gave you the timestamp. F=qE, the poynting vector is energy flow, not force. Like I said look at momentum conservation of EM, the stress tensor iz the main point of interest

Comment: In reality this energy flow is in fact a bunch of photons that move only forward with speed c. It is quite normal their momentum  conservation and that of electrons to bring movement right. Do you say there is no movement right at all (just on E up-down)?

Comment: There force is in the direction of $q(\vec{E} + \vec{v}×\vec{B})$

Comment: Newtons third law  and conservation of mechanical momentum, break down in electrodynamics. Conservation of EM momentum must be considered instead

Comment: Well true I forgot the magnetic force. Than things are ok.

Comment: In the end there oscillation up-down and right-left?

Answer (score 0):

Direction of $E$ in the incident wave does not necessarily coincide with the direction of $E$ in the rod. What you have is the problem of diffraction of a plane wave on an (infinite) homogeneous cylinder. To solve it, one expands the plane wave into cylindrical waves, in which waves $E$ depends on the azimuthal angle as $\exp(i n\phi)$. The amplitudes of the refracted waves (waves inside the cylinder) depend on the wavelength of the incident wave and permittivity, conductivity, and radius of the cylinder. There will be components $E_r$ and $E_\phi$ of the electric field (and electron movement) inside the cylinder.

Comment: Suppose the cylinder is infinite. I don't want to consider refracted waves. (stop time beforevEM reach the end) As far as I see the electrons will move up-down and left-right simultaneously. For the EM wave in a finite rod in the end one have standing wave = 1 wave left+ 1 wave right with lambda=L/2. I think electrons also will move up-down oscilation + left-right oscilation with w of the wave.